# Discord.js 13 buttons deleteReply()

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

When running the `deleteReply()` function, it throws an error:

```js
collector.on('collect', async i => {
            if(i.customId === 'stats') {
                await i.update({ embeds: [statsEmbed], components: [row] });
            }
            if(i.customId === 'exit'){
                await i.deleteReply();
            }
        });
```

I receive this error:

```
H:\Coding\discord-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^
DiscordAPIError: Unknown Webhook
    at RequestHandler.execute (H:\Coding\discord-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (H:\Coding\discord-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async InteractionWebhook.deleteMessage (H:\Coding\discord-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Webhook.js:366:5)
    at async ButtonInteraction.deleteReply (H:\Coding\discord-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:156:5) {
  method: 'delete',
  path: '/webhooks/849734263916986450/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246OTYyNjg0MDExMTY2MTgzNDY2OmRwUkRqdkN4Vk5CbzlDNHJXNjdONGNRTkNlVTJ1bGlFemNRdXdLRElHWDhkNk00MkVROWdDcEMzTmRmNjZ0VlZkaE9ibFJxeFo2UElqbm4yUmU4aU1wWEg5ODNzUGNiVElVR2RBRUoyRjJXNUhJSjN3NVhLWTVJVEZoM0xROTZn/messages/@original',
  code: 10015,
  httpStatus: 404,
  requestData: { json: undefined, files: [] }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the entire message that this element is attached to to delete, try this:

```js
if (i.customId === 'exit') {
    i.message.delete()
}
```